# How do I add Authentication/Authorization to an Azure App Service from a .NET desktop app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

there are lots of "quick starts" on how to add authentication/authorization to mobile apps, web pages...but I write desktop apps in WPF and UWP(less frequently). I have written an Azure App Service (webapi from VS 2017) but have not added authentication. It's supposed to be somewhat integrated within the app service but I need a quick start from a WPF app (logging in, passing tokens, setting up the Startup class in my webapi…) That's what I really need.

M

Answer (score 0):

The way of adding authentication/authorization to mobile apps is used Azure Mobile Service SDK (Both client SDK and backend SDK).

As you mentioned that you need to add same authentication/authorization to a WPF app, you should also use the client SDK and backend SDK like the way of lots of "quick starts".

We can use .NET SDK of Azure Mobile Service in our Client and Backend.

[How to use the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library)

[Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample application on Github that does almost exactly what you're looking for, i.e. quick start from WPF app calling web api . (Only small difference is that web api sample here is hosted on localhost instead of app service, but that's just deployment, not really much to do with code changes)

Let me know in case you were looking for something different or more details here. I came across this question while answering your other one :)

[image]

[Integrating Azure AD into a Windows desktop application using interactive authentication](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop)